# how to catch a System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader error in powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, custom-error-handling

The code looks like this:

```
foreach ($machine in $lbx_workstations.SelectedItems)
      {
      $temp = (get-winevent -computername $machine -FilterXML $commandString -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable eventerr|
         Select MachineName, TimeCreated, LevelDisplayName, ID, ProviderName, Message) 
blah blah blah...
```

I made a custom error variable, $eventerr, which works just fine when the get-winevent cmdlet can't find any events that match the criteria in the XML commandstring. However, the problem is this: If the XML commandstring is invalid, the error is created in the $error variable instead of the $eventerr variable. I'd like to get that error stored in my custom error variable, but I don't know where it is coming from or what is generating it. Or why it isn't already in my custom variable, actually. When I look at these two different types of errors, this is the output I get:

```
PS C:\Temp> $error[0].fullyqualifiederrorid
System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

PS C:\Temp> $error[1].fullyqualifiederrorid
NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

I can catch the "NoMatchingEventsFound" error in the custom variable, but not the System.Diagnostics.Eventing... error.

Is there any way to get the "System.Diagnostics.Eventing... error into my custom error variable?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening when PowerShell is trying to convert `$commandString` into an `XmlDocument` (the type of the `-FilterXml` parameter).  I don't think you'll be able to capture the error in your error variable since it is happening before the call into `Get-WinEvent`.  Your best bet is to validate `$commandString` before trying to pass it to `Get-WinEvent`.

```
try
{
    $xmlDoc = New-Object 'Xml.XmlDocument'
    $xmlDoc.LoadXml( $commandString )
}
catch
{
    # Or do some other kind of error handling.  You're the driver!
    Write-Error ('Oh no!  Bad XML!  What are you thinking?!')
}

$lbx_workstationg.SelectedItems |
    ForEach-Object { Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -FilterXml $commandString -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction eventerr } |
    Select-Object MachineName, TimeCreated, LevelDisplayName, ID, ProviderName, Message
```

That being said, I have noticed that sometimes using the `-ErrorVariable` doesn't result in all the errors from getting put in the error variable specified.  I never found out why.  I usually end up falling back to using `$Error`.  You can get the errors specific to your command by proper indexing:

```
$errorCount = $Error.Count
$lbx_workstationg.SelectedItems |
    ForEach-Object { Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -FilterXml $commandString -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } |
    Select-Object MachineName, TimeCreated, LevelDisplayName, ID, ProviderName, Message
$winEventError = $Error[0..($Error.Count - $errorCount)]
```

Comment: Your suggestion as to where the error is coming from, sounds likely. I tried the try-catch and it didn't catch it. Maybe because it looks ok until get-winevent evaluates it? The offending XML:
    <QueryList>
       <Query Id="0" Path="System">
          <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='msiinstaller'] (Level=3 or Level=1 or Level=2 )
             and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='2013-07-09T05:00:00.000Z' 
             and @SystemTime&lt;='2013-07-10T05:00:00.000Z' ]]]
          </Select>
       </Query>
    </QueryList>

You cant define the "Level" if you're using the "Provider".

Comment: Sorry... I couldn't figure out how to get the xml into a code block. >.<

Comment: That's valid XML.  Not sure why the error isn't getting caught.  I've found the `-ErrorVariable` doesn't work sometimes.  I usually fallback to `$Error`. :-|

Comment: I'm about to figure this out. Looks like it is something to do with how I coded it. Don't waste any more brain cells on it. I'll post the resolution when I can be clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

The two different errors make different types of error messages. These types have different properties. 
$eventerr.message holds the text I need if the error is
 
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException
The specified query is invalid

$eventerr.exception holds the error text if the error is this type:
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord
No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.

I'm not clear on how a single variable (eventerr) can hold different object types. But this seems to be the case. If anyone has a good explanation for how this can be, I'd sure like to hear it. Meanwhile, I'm going to mark this as the answer.